# Async Client Binance

Tags: python, binance, binance-api-client

I'm trying Async Client, and also, I'm not really familiar with async programming, so I'm trying to grasp it.

I'm confused about what the "`await client.close_connection()`" part does. Is it necessary to have that? Because the code just works fine without that.

Code:

```
async def main():
    client = await AsyncClient.create(config.API_KEY, config.API_SECRET_KEY, tld='com')
    bm = BinanceSocketManager(client)
    # start any sockets here, i.e a trade socket
    ts = bm.trade_socket('BTCUSDT')
    # then start receiving messages
    async with ts as tscm:
        while True:
            res = await tscm.recv()
            print(res)

    await client.close_connection()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: sometimes if you don't close connection then system (Windows, Linux, Mac) may keep open socket (for longer time) and you can't run code again. Or if you run program many  times then it may need to use new sockets/ports and finally system may have blocked all sockets/ports (it has some limit of ports) - and then problem can have other programs in system which need to use sockets (ie. web browser). It is good to close resource (socket, connection, file, etc) if you don't use it.